# Ajustar query sql de acordo com disciplina disponível

Tags: mysql

Possuo esta query, funcionando de boa, mas acontece que funciona apenas se tiver dados para as duas disciplinas PORTUGUES e MATEMATICA, como posso fazer para que, sem prejudicar o resultado, independente de haver apenas uma ou as duas disciplinas eu possa obter os resultados, segue abaixo apenas a parte da query que acho necessária, se preciso coloco o resto.

```
-- Campos a selecionar.
SELECT
AVG(IFNULL(pqas.fraction, 0)) * 10 AS MediaPT,
AVG(IFNULL(mqas.fraction, 0)) * 10 AS MediaMT,
gg.finalgrade AS NotaGeral,
u.firstname AS Aluno,
u.username AS Usuario,
u.lastname AS siem,
--  u.id, -- removido
u.department AS Turma,
u.institution AS Escola,
pqc.name AS catp,
mqc.name AS catm

FROM mdl_user u

INNER JOIN mdl_grade_grades gg ON gg.userid = u.id
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON gi.`id` = gg.`itemid`
INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempt_steps pqas ON u.id = pqas.userid
INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempts pqa ON pqa.id = pqas.questionattemptid
INNER JOIN mdl_question pq ON pq.id = pqa.questionid
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_slots pqs ON pqs.questionid = pqa.questionid AND pqs.slot = pqa.slot
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz pquiz ON pquiz.id = pqs.quizid
INNER JOIN mdl_question_categories pqc ON pqc.id = pq.category
INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempt_steps mqas ON u.id = mqas.userid
INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempts mqa ON mqa.id = mqas.questionattemptid
INNER JOIN mdl_question mq ON mq.id = mqa.questionid
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_slots mqs ON mqs.questionid = mqa.questionid AND mqs.slot = mqa.slot
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz mquiz ON mquiz.id = mqs.quizid
INNER JOIN mdl_question_categories mqc ON mqc.id = mq.category    

-- Parte do WHERE para filtrar apenas PORTUGUES nas tabelas p.
WHERE SUBSTR(pqc.name, 8) = "PORTUGUES"

-- Parte do WHERE para filtrar apenas matemática nas tabelas m.
AND SUBSTR(mqc.name, 8) = "MATEMATICA"

-- Final da query.
GROUP BY turma, u.id
ORDER BY turma ASC, `Aluno` ASC
```

Comment: Miguel, adicione os JOINS da `pqc` e `mqc` para a pergunta ficar correta...

Comment: @rbz adicionado

Comment: Dei uma ordenada no código, e corrigi o `WHERE` (o que eu tinha errado também na resposta) rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**resposta alterada após comentários**

Utilizando a validação via `OR` (já que os campos de controle são de tabelas diferentes), adicione também uma validação na consulta do campo; caso exista (português ou matemática), calcule a média.
Esta validação é necessária para que sejam exibidas as duas médias (caso existam) ou apenas uma:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (SUBSTR(pqc.name, 8) = 'PORTUGUES') THEN (AVG(IFNULL(pqas.fraction, 0)) * 10) ELSE NULL END AS MediaPT,
    CASE WHEN (SUBSTR(mqc.name, 8) = 'MATEMATICA') THEN (AVG(IFNULL(mqas.fraction, 0)) * 10) ELSE NULL END AS MediaMT,
    gg.finalgrade AS NotaGeral,
    u.firstname AS Aluno,
    u.username AS Usuario,
    u.lastname AS siem,
--  u.id, -- removido
    u.department AS Turma,
    u.institution AS Escola,
    pqc.name AS catp,
    mqc.name AS catm

FROM mdl_user u
-- join demais tabelas

WHERE SUBSTR(pqc.name, 8) = 'PORTUGUES'
   OR SUBSTR(mqc.name, 8) = 'MATEMATICA'

GROUP BY turma, u.id
ORDER BY turma ASC, `Aluno` ASC
```

Comment: Cara, não funciona porque são diferentes: `pqc` e `mqc`. Pelo que entendi, são tabelas diferentes que estão em `-- joins necessários ...`, `-- Parte do WHERE para filtrar apenas PORTUGUES nas tabelas p.` e  `-- Parte do WHERE para filtrar apenas matemática nas tabelas m.`

Comment: dessa vez eu que não reparei =p vou apagar minha resposta

Comment: normals ;) ....

Comment: poizé, estava pensando nisso, são tabelas que não existem na consulta; acho que a pergunta está errada.

Comment: @rLinhares dessa forma não vou ter problemas no resultado da nota de português e matematica quando tiver as duas disciplinas?

Comment: @rLinhares as tabelas existem sim, estão em ´joins necessários´ já havia pensado no OR, mas não serve

Comment: @MiguelSilva entendi o ponto, veja se a alteração atende.

Comment: @rLinhares vou testando

Comment: @rLinhares funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado

Comment: Agora surgiu um problema, quando há mais de uma turma, ele não filtra mesmo usando condição no where para me trazer apensa determinada turma

Comment: @MiguelSilva o ideal é manter o foco da pergunta; como o problema da pergunta já foi solucionado, é aconselhável deixar a pergunta respondida (para que alguém que busque a solução do problema original, encontre) e criar uma nova pergunta com a outra dúvida.

Comment: ok, marquei como resolvida novamente

Answer (score 2):

#### Como fazer

Você pode usar a cláusula `OR`:

```
SELECT
    AVG(IFNULL(pqas.fraction, 0)) * 10 AS MediaPT,
    AVG(IFNULL(mqas.fraction, 0)) * 10 AS MediaMT,
    gg.finalgrade AS NotaGeral,
    u.firstname AS Aluno,
    u.username AS Usuario,
    u.lastname AS siem,
--  u.id, -- removido
    u.department AS Turma,
    u.institution AS Escola,
    pqc.name AS catp,
    mqc.name AS catm
FROM mdl_user u

WHERE SUBSTR(pqc.name, 8) = "PORTUGUES"
   OR SUBSTR(mqc.name, 8) = "MATEMATICA"

GROUP BY turma, u.id
ORDER BY turma ASC, `Aluno` ASC
```

---

#### Explicando

Linha:

```
WHERE SUBSTR(pqc.name, 8) = "PORTUGUES"
       OR SUBSTR(mqc.name, 8) = "MATEMATICA"
```

A função `OR` fará com que a query traga os resultados de:

`SUBSTR(pqc.name, 8) = "PORTUGUES"` **OU** (OR) `SUBSTR(mqc.name, 8) = "MATEMATICA"`

Comment: alterei a resposta porque estava sem `where` (não fazia sentido)

Comment: @rLinhares Opa, nem tinha reparado! ✌️